# Navigate in Dictionaries

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, navigation

I'm stuck at navigating on dictionary generated by loading json from [here](https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/24657246,20618409,33953490,43685290,58298425,69487466,23250986,72110165,66369619,37902970/entry?api_key=2c0543ab-aeca-476d-8276-a5c23748898c). Can someone help me please. Thanks in adv.
I tried `tier_d[test - 1] = data[summoners[test - 1]['entries']['leaguePoints']]` but it tells me `expected integers`. I want to fetch 'leaguePoints' from it.

Summoners_id are ids provided from another request, they look like '24657246' for example

```
url = 'https://{0}.api.pvp.net/api/lol/{0}/v2.5/league/by-summoner/{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}/entry?api_key={11}'.format(region, summoner_id_1, summoner_id_2, summoner_id_3, summoner_id_4, summoner_id_5, summoner_id_6, summoner_id_7, summoner_id_8, summoner_id_9, summoner_id_10, key)
print(url)
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
tier = ['Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked', 'Unranked']
tier_d = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

done = False
test = 0

rankeds = []

for ids in data:
    rankeds.append(ids)

    print(rankeds)
print(summoners)

while test <= 9:
    test += 1
    if summoners[test - 1] in rankeds:
        tier_d[test - 1] = data[summoners[test - 1]['entries']['leaguePoints']]
        tier[test - 1] = data[summoners[test - 1]][0]['tier']
        print(data[summoners[test - 1]][0]['tier'])

    print(tier)
```

Comment: Please show your code. Read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code example is not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some `lists` and `dictionaries` nested in each other. You have to carefully go through them.

The output of `data[summoners[test - 1]]` is:

```
[{'entries': [{'division': 'I',
    'isFreshBlood': False,
    'isHotStreak': False,
    'isInactive': False,
    'isVeteran': False,
    'leaguePoints': 0,
    'losses': 14,
    'playerOrTeamId': 'xxyyzz',
    'playerOrTeamName': 'xxyyzz',
    'wins': 8}],
  'name': "Talon's Army",
  'queue': 'xxyyzz',
  'tier': 'BRONZE'},
 {'entries': [{'division': 'V',
    'isFreshBlood': False,
    'isHotStreak': False,
    'isInactive': False,
    'isVeteran': False,
    'leaguePoints': 18,
    'losses': 2,
    'playerOrTeamId': 'xxyyzz',
    'playerOrTeamName': 'xxyyzz',
    'wins': 5}],
  'name': "xxyyzz",
  'queue': 'xxyyzz',
  'tier': 'SILVER'}]
```

So this should give you the `leaguePoints` value:

```
tier_d[test - 1] = data[summoners[test - 1]][0]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints']
tier_d[test - 1] = data[summoners[test - 1]][1]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints']
```

depending on the first or second entry in the list.

Comment: <3 I appreciate the help, I was trying without the '[0]' after 'entries', i dont perfectly understand how the tree works :/ but i'll learn, thanks again